# How to translate requirements into Java?

Tags: java

In *Java Programming*, 8th Edition, Joyce Farrell, Chp. 2,

Sammy's seashore supplies rents beach equipment such as kayaks, canoes, beach chairs, and umbrellas to tourists

Write a program that prompts the user for the number of minutes he rented a piece of sports equipment.

Compute the rental cost as $40 per hour plus 41 per additional minute.  (You might have surmised already that this rate has a logical flaw, but for now, calculate rates as described here. You can fix the problem after you read the chapter on decision making).

Display the hours, minutes, and total price.

Comment: Java is not Javascript, at all

Comment: Your question title is inaccurate. It shouldn't be updated to "Java example" either as you are not asking for code to be converted to another language.

Comment: if you have javascript, you already have code

Comment: Are you asking for someone to write this program for you (which is _probably_ not going to happen), or for someone to explain the general process of translating requirements into Java code (which is _definitely_ not going to happen)?  Either way, I don't think it's on topic for this site.  I have voted to close.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to learn JavaScript, you're probably reading the wrong book.  Java is an entirely different language.  (Well, a _mostly_ different language).

Comment: The class is Java, not Java script.  I never asked anyone to do the work for me.  What sense would that make when I am learning to code.  I asked how do I translate the scenario.  I don't have a starting point of how to plan the program logic.

Comment: Why is everyone writing about JavaScript.  The name of the book I listed is Java programming.  I am not asking about JavaScript.  The class is java.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class SammysRentalPrice {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final int RENT_PER_HOUR = 40;
            final int RENT_PER_ADDITIONAL_MINUTE = 1;
            final int MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR = 60;
            int minutesRented;
            int hoursRented;
            int additionalMinutes;
            int total;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("SsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSs");
            System.out.println("Ss                                      Ss");
            System.out.println("Ss   Sammy's makes it fun in the sun.   Ss");
            System.out.println("Ss                                      Ss");
            System.out.println("SsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSsSs");
            System.out.print("Enter the number of minutes you want to rent for >>>");
            minutesRented = input.nextInt();
            hoursRented = minutesRented / MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR;
            additionalMinutes = minutesRented % MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR;
            total = hoursRented * RENT_PER_HOUR + additionalMinutes * 
    RENT_PER_ADDITIONAL_MINUTE;
            System.out.println("No. of hours rented: " + hoursRented + " hour");
            System.out.println("No. of additional minuted rented: " + 
    additionalMinutes + " minutes");
            System.out.println("Total rent: $" + total);
        }}
```